# Webpack hooks with multiple OS

Tags: webpack-4

Our development team is on both Windows and Linux.  I have created a webpack 4 plugin using compiler hooks that works only on Linux machines.  Is there a way to detect OS so I can write an alternate version for the Windows folks?

```
plugins: [
  {
    apply: (compiler) => {
      compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap("AfterEmitPlugin", () => {
        exec("sh generate-templates.sh src/main/resources/public/js", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (stdout) process.stdout.write(stdout);
          if (stderr) process.stderr.write(stderr);
        });
      });
    },
  },
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the plugin in Node.js instead of shell and there shouldn't be an issue with OS compatibility.

```
plugins: [
  {
    apply: (compiler) => {
      compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap("AfterEmitPlugin", () => {
        ...use node here.
      });
    },
  },
],
```

Comment: It's better and helpful to other by showing how you code plugin in node.js